# How to send datasource to subreport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I work at a report that need a subreport, so I want to pass datasource from a Java method to subreport, but I don't arrive at the correct way. Usually I use the followin piece of code to create my report. What is the correct way to send datasource to subreport?

```
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
param.put("rapportNom", "Module");
param.put("PAR_IMAGE_BACKGROUND", "/dz/suivi/reporting/sources/BackgroundElit.png");
param.put("PAR_IMAGE_HEADER", "/dz/suivi/reporting/sources/headerElit.png");
param.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "/dz/suivi/reporting/sources/moduleAllDetail_subreport1.jasper");
param.put("SUBREPORT_DATA", "LIST OF OBJECT");

return Reporting.printEtat(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dz/suivi/reporting/sources/moduleAllDetail.jasper"),
                param, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportingModuleViewFacade.findById(module)));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have your datasource as a `List<MyBean>` as simple method is:

1. **Pass it** in the parameter map

   ```
   param.put("SUBREPORT_DATA", myBeanList);
   ```
2. **Define** the parameter in jrxml

   ```
   <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DATA" class="java.util.List"/>
   ```
3. **Create** a [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) using your parameter

   ```
   <subreport>
       <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" uuid="406c9014-e74b-42d9-b9e1-4af106bfb779"/>
       <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{SUBREPORT_DATA})]]></dataSourceExpression>
       <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "theSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an [article](http://starredmediasoft.com/category/report/jasper-reports/) for programming and configuring jasperreport with report, subreport and datasources:

For subreport:

> When attaching a subreport to the master report, it’s important to set
>   the Expression and the Data Source expression properties;
>
> Expression property is used to find out which report to use, while the
>   Data Source is the data attached on the subreport.
>
> While Expression can be set to the relative path of the subreport
>   .jasper (ex. “report/subreport.jasper”), it is also possible to load
>   the compiled jasper from another source like an input stream.
>
> For this purpose, create a parameter in the master report (in this
>   case called PersonsSubReport) and set the Expression property to
>   $P{PersonsSubReport}.
>
> In this way it’s possible to inject the subreport from the code on the
>   fill and build process. (We’ll see it later)
>
> Set Data Source expression to:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{persons})
```